# Getting StorageAccount-AccessKey in Pulumi Azure Native

Tags: azure, pulumi

I am trying to switch from "classic" Azure to Azure Native in Pulumi. One of my requirements is to retrieve the Connectionstring and AccessKey to my newly created StorageAccount.

On classic Azure I received those fields by

```
var connectionString=ClassicStorageAccount.PrimaryConnectionString;
var accessKey=ClassicStorageAccount.PrimaryAccessKey;
```

where `ClassicStorageAccount` is of type `Pulumi.Azure.Storage.Account`

Now after creating a storage account with Azure Native:

```
var account=new Pulumi.AzureNative.Storage.StorageAccount("myMagicAccount", new StorageAccountArgs{...});
```

I am struggling to retrieve the AccessKey.

I am able to retrieve the connectionstring using

```
var connectionstring=account.StorageAccount.PrimaryEndpoints.Apply(q=>q.Web);
```

but none of the properties from `PrimaryEndpoints` or `PrivateEndpointConnections` seem to contain my required AccessKey.

The [docs for StorageAccount on Azure Native](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azure-native/storage/storageaccount/) did not help me on this approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a [listStorageAccountKeys](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azure-native/storage/liststorageaccountkeys/) method you can use.

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Pulumi;
using Pulumi.AzureNative.Resources;
using Pulumi.AzureNative.Storage;
using Pulumi.AzureNative.Storage.Inputs;

class MyStack : Stack
{
    public MyStack()
    {
        // Create an Azure Resource Group
        var resourceGroup = new ResourceGroup("resourceGroup");

        // Create an Azure resource (Storage Account)
        var storageAccount = new StorageAccount("sa", new StorageAccountArgs
        {
            ResourceGroupName = resourceGroup.Name,
            Sku = new SkuArgs
            {
                Name = SkuName.Standard_LRS
            },
            Kind = Kind.StorageV2
        });

        // Export the primary key of the Storage Account
        this.PrimaryStorageKey = Output.Tuple(resourceGroup.Name, storageAccount.Name).Apply(names =>
            Output.CreateSecret(GetStorageAccountPrimaryKey(names.Item1, names.Item2)));
    }

    [Output]
    public Output<string> PrimaryStorageKey { get; set; }

    private static async Task<string> GetStorageAccountPrimaryKey(string resourceGroupName, string accountName)
    {
        var accountKeys = await ListStorageAccountKeys.InvokeAsync(new ListStorageAccountKeysArgs
        {
            ResourceGroupName = resourceGroupName,
            AccountName = accountName
        });
        return accountKeys.Keys[0].Value;
    }
}
```

Code above is from the template Pulumi uses when you run `pulumi new azure-csharp` and can be found in the templates repository